# Get Mailbox Permissions using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm creating an app that needs to get the permissions for each MailBox, and I can't seem to get it to work. I've noticed in the VS Object Browser that the [Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.permissions(v=exchg.80).aspx) property is on the [Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) class.

So I'm guessing I need to get the [MailBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.mailbox%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) object and then get the root/default folder so I can get the Permissions.

This is what I've done so far, but when it calls `Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, sharedMailboxRootFolderId);` I get the following exception:

> "The Client Access Server version does not match the accessed
>   resource's Mailbox Server version."

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
string exchangeServerWebServicesUrl = "https://example.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
service.Url = new Uri(exchangeServerWebServicesUrl);

string username = "*********************";
string password = "*********************";

service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);

Mailbox sharedMailbox = new Mailbox("shared@example.com");

FolderId sharedMailboxRootFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, sharedMailbox);
Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, sharedMailboxRootFolderId);

var permissions = rootfolder.Permissions;
```

I've tried passing in different ExchangeVersion enum values, but they don't work either. But passing ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1 does work when I try and get the Public Folders root folder.

```
Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);
```

So the question is how can I get a MailBoxes permissions using EWS?

Answer (score 6):

I've just found the [Find out which users have Full Access on a mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670746/find-out-which-users-have-full-access-on-a-mailbox/25678860#25678860) post that says

> You can't using EWS (or any of the Exchange Mailbox API's) you can
> only access the Folder level DACL's what you need to read is the
> Mailbox DACL which can only be either accessed via the Exchange
> Management Shell (Get-MailboxPermissions) or via reading the
> msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor from Active Directory.

So it looks like it's not possible to get the MailBox permissions using EWS.
Shame.